# how we can change the div content by clicking on menu bar without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

```
<div id="containerright">
  <div id="containerrighttop">
    <ul>
      <li><a  href="C:\Users\Ravi Ranjan\Desktop\new web\New folder/content-  1.     html">Content 1</a></li>
      <li><a  href="C:\Users\Ravi Ranjan\Desktop\new web\New folder/content-2.html">Content 2</a></li>
      <li><a  href="C:\Users\Ravi Ranjan\Desktop\new web\New folder/content-3.html">Content 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="containerrightbottom">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

** this is my scripting with ajax**
in this i want  menubar in horizontal way so that on click on that menu bar the div content on one part of same page get change with out  page refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $("#conatinerright""#containerrighttop").click(function() {

            $("#conatinerright""#containerrightbottom" ).load($(this).attr("href"));

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: instead of $("#conatinerright""#containerrighttop") use $("#conatinerright #containerrighttop").html()

Comment: You missed `,` in `$("#conatinerright""#containerrighttop")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#containerrighttop a").click(function() {
        $("#containerrightbottom").load($(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Your problems were:

1. You misspelled `#containerright`. This part of the selector isn't needed, since the ID of the inner DIV is sufficient.
2. You used invalid syntax by putting two strings next to each other with no `+` to concatenate them.
3. You bound the click handler to `#containerrighttop`, but it should be bound to the anchors.

Comment: its working but page is open in nother page plz help

Comment: I don't think you can use AJAX to read local files, you have to read them from a webserver.